# Twilio: JavaScript SDK: How do I page through conversations for a participant?

Tags: javascript, typescript, twilio

I have a Twilio serverless function that sends an outbound message to a customer. This works well unless there's already an active conversation with the participant. My team has decided to close any active conversation with the participant as a first step, then open up a new one from there, for now.

Here's a starting TypeScript function that gets all active conversations for a participant:

```
// ...
// TODO: There might be a better name for this or better way to import. There's the global Twilio that serverless functions use that
// doesn't need imported (GlobalTwilio shows on occasion for this), then there's the Twilio module that's used
// elsewhere more often like non-serverless Node scripts making Twilio calls. This is understandably
// more confusing because it's pulling from the serverless runtime types node_modules... I'll inquire about
// best way forward separately.
import * as NonServerlessTwilio from '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio';
// ...

// Get a list of active conversations for a customer phone number
const getActiveConversations = async (client: NonServerlessTwilio, customerPhoneNumber: string) => {
  try {
    const allConversations = await client.conversations.v1.participantConversations.list({
      address: customerPhoneNumber,
      limit: 1000
    });

    const activeConversations = allConversations.filter((conversation) => conversation.conversationState === 'active');

    return activeConversations;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('getActiveConversations error', (err as Error).message);
    return [];
  }
};
```

Challenge:

In the event we have a very active customer or the participant is a developer posting lots of messages (me), how do I get past the 1000 limit? Pagination seems like a good step. I see I could call:

```
client.conversations.v1.participantConversations.getPage()
```

I just don't know how that works. Am I able to pass in parameters or is `getPage()` a second step? What's the best way to proceed in order to get all active conversations for a participant?

Comment: Separate from the SDK, I saw that I could get all active conversations via the API e.g. `https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations?PageSize=1000&State=active`. However, these require an extra call to get participants. That could be a lot of API calls when there are a lot of agent conversations happening at once. Targetting all conversations for a participant and filtering active from there feels like a better option (if pagination is an option).